# AWS EC2 Segmentation Fault (core dumped) issue with fast-style-transfer

Tags: aws, neural-style-transfer

I'm trying to utilize *AWS EC2 p2.xlarge* instance to convert images using style-transfer code given in this git repo:https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer.git, yet when the input file becomes large, I keep running into this error:

```
2018-09-12 02:55:25.797741: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports 
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: 
SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-09-12 02:55:25.797880: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:69] Creating new thread 
pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using 
inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This happens when the file size of the input is bigger than 130kb...yet works fine when the input is smaller than a certain size around 130kb. This defeats the purpose of using AWS, as any file of that small size would convert quite quickly on my computer too.

If anyone wants the files that I've used for testing, I could also upload it on the question.

Comment: What's Nvidia-smi/nvcc giving? Seems like the GPU is out of memy

Comment: Have you checked the version of tensorflow running on aws? I believe that this instance comes with 12GB gpu memory and thus gpu memory should not be a problem. Also check the input dimensions in the code. If they are too large, tune them appropriately as it would drastically affect the number of parameters in the model causing this core dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue.Just use `tensorflow-gpu=1.5.0`.

Follow these steps:

`$ pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
$ pip install tensorflow==1.5.0
$ pip install numpy==1.14.0
$ pip install six==1.10.0
$ pip install joblib==0.12`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This actually worked!!

Answer (score 2):

It might be a result of how you setup the instance. The GPU version of TensorFlow installed using `conda` or `pip` is not always optimized for certain hardware configurations. You can try to build TensorFlow from source, directions for an AWS EC2 p2.xlarge can be found [here](https://medium.com/@rogerxujiang/setting-up-a-gpu-instance-for-deep-learning-on-aws-795343e16e44).

Comment: but its actually weird that its happening on a p2 instance

Comment: I was actually using conda, so maybe that's the reason for this problem? Thanks for the reply; at least I have somewhere to get started on a solution.